# Redirecting to new page in tab with query string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

On click of graph I want to open new page in tab to diplay some data.
And want to send some data also.

I am using below code :

```
Response.Redirect("MonthData.aspx?Name=" + "Preeti" + "&Year=" + (Date.Now.Year).ToString, False)
```

But this is opening page in existing window.
Please suggest.**I can't use hyperlink as opening page on click event of graph**.

Answer (score 0):

The `Target` property of the `<asp:HyperLink>` control set to `_blank` is what you want to use to make a hyperlink open a new page and the `NavigateUrl` property to control the redirect location, like this:

Markup:

```
<asp:HyperLink id="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text="Send Data" Target="_blank" />
```

Code-behind

```
HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "MonthData.aspx?Name=" + "Preeti" + "&Year=" + (Date.Now.Year).ToString()
```

The potential values for `Target` are:

- _blank
- _parent
- _search
- _self
- _top

Read [HyperLink.Target Property documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.target%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Karl.But I am working on click event of graph.Cannot use hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

Added below code in chart series :

```
tmpchart.Series(0).Url = "MonthData.aspx"
tmpchart.Series(0).MapAreaAttributes = "target=""_blank"""
```

It's working fine now.